# what is the best way to create session from java spring boot using oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot

I created user in oracle database and I am trying to create session but I find many ways in spring boot so what is the easy way if I want to create classe connections using the Username and Password  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `jdbc template`, `spring data JDBC` or `spring data JPA`, well depending on your use case.

If your data model is quite complex, you should avoid using the `JDBC template` as you will need to write prepared statements which can be cumbersome. JPA will allow you to use object-oriented programming principles and also will help you map the entities to your database columns.

For example, if you are going to use `spring data JPA`, you need to set the application properties as follows:

```
spring.datasource.type=oracle.oracleucp.jdbc.UCPDataSource
spring.datasource.oracleucp.connection-factory-class-name=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource 
spring.datasource.oracleucp.sql-for-validate-connection=select * from dual 
spring.datasource.oracleucp.connection-pool-name=UcpPoolBooks 
spring.datasource.oracleucp.initial-pool-size=5 
spring.datasource.oracleucp.min-pool-size=5 
spring.datasource.oracleucp.max-pool-size=10
```

This would behind the scene create an Oracle Datasource. In this example, we are using `Oracle Universal Connection Pooling`. You can also use `HikariCP` which is quite popular.

[check this out](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-vs-jdbc#pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [UCP with above properties](https://If%20you%20want%20to%20use%20%5BUCP%20with%20above%20properties%5D%5B1%5D%20then%20you%20must%20have%20SpringBoot%20version%20higher%20than%202.4.0.%20%20%20Check%20out%20the%20%5BSpring%20Boot%20code%20sample%20on%20GitHub%5D%5B1%5D.%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-db-examples/blob/main/java/SpringBootApp/src/main/resources/application.properties) then you must have SpringBoot version higher than 2.4.0.

Check out the [Spring Boot code sample on GitHub](https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-db-examples/blob/main/java/SpringBootApp/).